# How i can change my query to work in django?

Tags: django

I want to make a request from two tables at once, I registered dependencies in the class. But the request does not work for me. What is wrong with him?

views.py

```
def payments(request):
     paymentsss = Transaction.objects.select_related("currency_id")[:5]
     return render(request, "payments.html", {"paymentsss": paymentsss})
```

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    currency_id = models.ForeignKey(Currency, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deal_id = models.ForeignKey(Deal, null=True, related_name='deal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_instance_id = models.ForeignKey(ServiceInstance, null=True, related_name='service_instance', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_source_id = models.ForeignKey(PayerPaymentSource, null=True, related_name='payment_source', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"processing"."transaction"'`enter code here`
```

And Currency for example:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
id = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
iso_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
minor_unit = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = '"processing"."currency"'
```

My Error:
[image]

I would be glad if there is an example of how to make a larger request. From 3-4 tables.

Comment: You used quotes in the name of your tables?

Comment: No, I do not use quotes.

Comment: what is this then? `db_table = '"processing"."currency"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the column names for the foreign keys: e.g. `currency = ForeignKey(...)` and `deal = ForeignKey(...)`.

The field is a reference to the **object** itself, not to the **id** of the object. You can see that behind the scenes, Django queries using `currency_id_id` which doesn't make sense.

If your column name is `currency_id` (in your database), then your field name should be `currency`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the db_table

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'processing.transaction'

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'processing.currency'
```

Comment: I would also advise to change the column name for the foreign key: `currency = ForeignKey(...)` and `deal = ForeignKey(...)`. The field is a reference to the **object** itself, not to the **id** of the object. You can see that behind the scenes, Django queries using `currency_id_id` which doesn't make sense. If your column name is `currency_id` (in your database), then your field name should be `currency`.

Comment: @dirkgroten, you can make it as an answer, because It helped)

Comment: Use of either double or single will work but both at the same time will not work.

Comment: @KARMVEERSINGH actually it seems it doesn't matter (although it doesn't deserve the prize for good coding style), the docs say: **Django quotes column and table names behind the scenes**. So if you do it in `db_table`, you've already done what Django would do anyway.